# From notification to fragment before app is first time launched?

Tags: android, android-fragments, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an app where I want to, when user click on push notification, to send him on fragment(I called him FragmentSRB) on MainActivity. Everything is okay when app is in the foreground or in the background. But when I kill application, and then I receive notification, notification sends me just to the main activity, not to the FragmentSRB. What should I do?

Here is myFirebaseMessagingService:

```
public class myFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG="MyFirebaseMsgService";
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.d(TAG, "From " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Body " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    sendNotification(remoteMessage);
    Log.d("Msg", "Poruka je stigla");
}

private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
    Intent intent=new Intent(myFirebaseMessagingService.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("action", "goToFragmentSRB");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(logo)
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setContentTitle("Naslov")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification.build());



}
```

And my mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button dugme, dugme2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("onCreate", "ONCREATE");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String msg = getIntent().getStringExtra("action");
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if (msg != null) {
        if (msg.equals("goToFragment1")) {
            Fragment1 fragment1 = new FragmentSRB();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, fragmentSRB);
            Log.d("FragmentTransaction", "Fragment je promenjen u onCreate!");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            Log.d("Create", "Kraj onCreatea");
        }
    }

    dugme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dugme1);
    dugme2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribe);
    dugme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            if (view == dugme) {
                fragment = new Fragment1();
            }
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });


    dugme2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("android");
            Log.d("Log", "Uspesno ste se pretplatili");
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Log.d("onNewIntent", "NewIntent");
    String msg = getIntent().getStringExtra("action");
    Log.d("Msg", "msg");
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if (msg != null) {
        if (msg.equals("goToFragment1")) {
            Fragment1 fragment1 = new FragmentSRB();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, fragmentSRB);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("onResume", "Resume");
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    String msg = getIntent().getStringExtra("action");
    Log.d("msg", "msg");
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if (msg != null) {
        if (msg.equals("goToFragment1")) {
            Fragment1 fragment1 = new FragmentSRB();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, fragmentSRB);
            Log.d("FragmentTransaction", "Fragment je promenjen!");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            Log.d("onResume", "Kraj resuma");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refer about @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){}. 
onNewIntent() is meant as entry point for singleTop activities which already run somewhere else in the stack and therefore can't call onCreate()

Comment: So, what should I do? To delete onNewIntent or something else do you have on mind?

Comment: Override onNewIntent() in your activity,and put your logic for replacing fragment in bot oncreate() and onNewIntent().

Comment: Try some logs and observe the how android calls these methods in different scenarios,so that u can understand whats actually happening here

Comment: So, if I have understand you correctly, I just need to uncomment this onNewIntent?

Comment: Where do you commented onNewIntent(), i cant see it in your code,it only have onCreate() method.

Comment: I have uncomment onNewIntent and edited post...

Comment: I think it is not required add fragment change logic in onResume(),also in onNewIntent() you don't need to call getIntent() because the methond already have intent as value onNewIntent(Intent intent)

Comment: i think now its should works in all scenarios

Comment: So, what should I do now?

Comment: just remove onResume() method and keep rest of the code unchanged.and check the result,it should work

Comment: And onNewIntent stays like this? I dont have to change anything?

Comment: Pls check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button dugme, dugme2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("onCreate", "ONCREATE");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        handleIntentExtra(intent);

        dugme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dugme1);
        dugme2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribe);
        dugme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Fragment fragment = null;
                if (view == dugme) {
                    fragment = new Fragment1();
                }
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });


        dugme2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("android");
                Log.d("Log", "Uspesno ste se pretplatili");
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        handleIntentExtra(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntentExtra(Intent intent) {
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("action");
        Log.d("Msg", "msg");
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if (msg != null) {
            if (msg.equals("goToFragment1")) {
                Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, fragment1);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        }
    }}
```

Comment: Sorry mate, I didn't write good exact problem. I can go to fragment when app is first time launched, but when I kill app, and I receive notification(and my app is not launched yet), then I go to mainActivity, not to the FragmentSRB...I hope you have understand me..